# How do I include my own zone file in /etc/com.apple.named.proxy.conf

Tags: dns, internet-sharing

When I enable internet connection sharing, a local named DNS nameserver is started that uses the file /etc/com.apple.named.proxy.conf for configuration.

My internet connection sharing is configured such that my Mac gets address 192.168.2.1

On my Mac, I have a local web server with several development vhosts. I would like to make their names known to devices that connect through the shared internet connection. I try this by including this section into com.apple.named.proxy.conf:

```
zone "local" IN {
    type master;
    file "vhosts.zone";
    allow-update { none; };
};
```

My problem is that the file /etc/com.apple.named.proxy.conf gets recreated on every new sharing session and any modifications I make to this file are lost.

Is there a source or template file from which com.apple.named.proxy.conf is created?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to the file `/etc/hosts` - this is read by the DNS server before it goes to any other source.

You will need to add a line

```
192.168.2.1   machine alias1 alias2 alias3
```

Obviously replace "machine" and the other items with the correct values.

Comment: I understand that /etc/hosts can be used to name vhosts on the local machine. However, I would like to publish vhost names to devices that connect through the shared internet connection. /etc/hosts will not be published through DNS as far as I see.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking to do exactly the same thing so if you have found a solution to this and could publish it that would be great.

Some investigation I have done:
- I have added the entry manually to the file only to have it blown away trying to re-read the file by starting and stopping sharing
- Starting and stopping sharing regenerates the /etc/com.apple.named.proxy.conf file. You can see this by looking at the file creation time. It will correlate to the time you started sharing.

So the trick then becomes where is the default or template file for this. It doesn't look promising that when you cat the binary of InternetSharing you can see the proxy conf within the binary
sed -n 555,599p /usr/libexec/InternetSharing 
for me shows pretty much the same content as 
cat /etc/com.apple.named.proxy.conf

Comment: Hi, welcome to AskDifferent, your question is posted as an answer. If your problem is the same as the question above you should upvote the question, as you can see it has been answered already, so you should also upvote the relevant answer.  Please take time to read the [help](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help) page.